# How to render a React component multiple times but each time with an updated State?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So I am working on a react project. I have a text area where I enter data and then that data is hashed and a Block with the Block number, hashed data and time is rendered on the screen whenever a button is clicked. However, when I enter the data again and hit the button again, it just rerenders the block as block number 2. I want the previous block to remain on screen and a new block to be rendered below the previous block whenever I click the button. How do I solve this? I have tried a lot but nothing seems to work. I am in the learning stages of react so please excuse me if this question seems trivial.

App.js

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import BlockList from './BlockList.js';
import InputText from './InputText.js';
import Button from './Button.js';

constructor() {
  super();
  console.log('constructor invoked')
  this.state = {
    blockno:0,
    Data:'',
    hash:'',
    showDiv: false

  }

onButtonClick = (event) => {
  console.log('onButtonClick invoked')
  this.setState({blockno: this.state.blockno + 1, showDiv: true})  
}

}

render() {

  return(
    <div>
<InputText onSearchChange={this.OnSearchChange}/>
<Button onButtonClick={this.onButtonClick} />
       {
          this.state.showDiv
          ?
            <div>

              <BlockList blockno={this.state.blockno} Data={this.state.Data} />

            </div>
          : ''          
        }



    </div>
    );
}

}

export default App;
```

Block.js

```
import React from 'react';
import SHA256 from 'sha256-es';

const Block = ({blockno,Data}) => {




        const hashdata = () =>{
            return(
                SHA256.hash(Data)
                );
            }
var today = new Date();
var dd = String(today.getDate()).padStart(2, '0');
var mm = String(today.getMonth() + 1).padStart(2, '0'); //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
return(
<div className="tc ws-pre">
    <h1 className="underline">Block {blockno}</h1>
    <h2>Data: {Data}</h2>
    <h2>Hash: {hashdata()}</h2>
    <h2>Date: {today}</h2>
</div>




        );


}

export default Block
```

BlockList.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Block from './Block.js';


const BlockList = ({blockno,Data,isBlockUpdated}) => {

    const BlockItems = () => {
        return(
            <div>
                {console.log('A block item is now returned')}
                <Block blockno={blockno} Data={Data} />
            </div>  
            );
    }

return(

<div>

    <BlockItems />


</div>

    );

}

export default BlockList
```

I want to display a new block below the previous one every time I click the button.

Comment: your `BlockList` indeed only ever has a single block in it. I don't have time now to figure out and type up a full working code snippet, but what you'll need to do is pass in an array of block ids to this component (and add to this each time the appropriate action happens), and `map` over that to render multiple `Block` components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just had a quick look through. So each time you press the button in App.js you're adding 1 to `blockno` in the state. This is just a number so that number is just being updated and passed down into Block.js

If you want to display multiple blocks you need to create an array that you can iterate over and display a Block component for each block.

Essentially you're state needs to be something like this:

```
blocks: [{ block data here }]
```

onButtonClick then needs to add an object to that array. Then you can pass that array down to BlockList and you can iterate over it there.

BlockList then looks something like this:

```
{blocks.map(block => (
  <Block data={block.data} />
))}
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1):

As DanBonehill's answer, you need an array to store the blocks

App.js

```
constructor() {
  super();
  console.log('constructor invoked')
  this.state = {
    // To store the list of blocks
    blocks: [],

  }
}

onButtonClick = (event) => {
  console.log('onButtonClick invoked')
  let blocks = this.state.blocks

  // Create a new block with current data and time
  blocks.push({data: this.state.Data, time: Date.time()})
  this.setState({blocks})  
}

render() {
    // other stuff here
    {
          this.state.blocks.length > 0
          ?
            <div>
              <BlockList blocks={this.state.blocks} />
            </div>
          : ''          
        }
}
```

BlockList.js

```
const BlockList = ({blocks,Data,isBlockUpdated}) => {
    // other stuff here


    return(
        <div>
            {blocks.map((block, index) => <BlockItem {...block} blockno={index} />)}
        </div>
    );
}
```